# Backbone on fetch success, model not consoling

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

Using fetch method, i am getting the models from my local json, but ofter success, nothing is consoling me..

any issue on my code.. as will which the way i am calling my render function is correct on success?

JSON i use :

```
[
    {'name':'student1'},
    {'name':'student2'},
    {'name':'student3'}
];
```

my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var school = {};

    school.model = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults:{
            name:'name yet to decide'    
        }    
    });

    school.collect = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model:school.model,
        url:'js/school.json',
        initialize:function(){
            console.log(this.collection)//shows the undefined
        }
    });

    school.view = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize:function(){
            var that = this;
            this.collection = new school.collect;
            this.collection.fetch({
                success:function(model,response){       
                    console.log(model,response);//i am not get any mode or response here
                    that.render(); //not at all calling..
                }
            });
        },
        render:function(){
            console.log('hi')
        }
    });

    var newModel = new school.model;

    var newSchool = new school.view({model:newModel});

})
```

Comment: If you put a breakpoint inside your 'success' function, does it get hit?  If not, then your fetch is not succeeding.  Try putting an 'error' callback and see if that is hit.

Comment: Is my json has anything wrong?

Comment: I changed my json from single quote to double quote now it works!

Comment: @3gwebtrain Great. Yes, JSON must be double-quotes. Rather than a comment, could you add your solution as the answer so the question does not look unanswered?